# Bash as float calculator

Tags: bash, shell, python, bc

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402181/how-do-i-get-bc1-to-print-the-leading-zero) to write a function that calculates floating-point numbers.

```
mt (){
echo "$1" | bc -l | awk '{printf "%f", $0}'
echo ' ' 
}
```

This works great, but I was wondering if there is a way to **omit the function call entirely** taking advantage of the error message that is returned when an operation of floats is attempted.

```
$ 45.0+1.2
-bash: 45.0+1.2: command not found
```

Is this doable? If so, how?

### EDIT

I guess the downvotes mean I didn't think this through, although a clarifying comment would be helpful.

I was using the *mt* function for calculations, but I often forget the mt when doing many of them in a short period. An initial and unique function call would do, and for that purpose **I could simply use python and call it a day.**

Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: `echo $(( (450+12) /100))`

Comment: I don't get it. Can you elaborate on how an error message could help doing a floating point calculation without a call to `bc`?

Comment: If the error message contains floats and operands, evaluate it. As I said in the edit, it's a silly idea and I should simply use python if I have to make more than a few calculations in a row.

Comment: The command_not_found error handler is one way... (A version that won't run potentially dangerous stuff pasted into a terminal accidentally might be trickier) (The prompt have a risk on pasting anyway though). Another method might be to mess with the "tab" completing code...

Comment: @CalculusKnight: You might want to look at http://xon.sh/ (I'm not convinced it is a good idea, the behavior seems unpredictable, depending on variables that exist...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this somewhere where it would be loaded into your bash environment: (`~/.bashrc` is one option) (**It is a bad idea** and won't work for division without spaces, see man page excerpt for why) (The exit is needed only for some non-GAWK AWK versions)

```
command_not_found_handle() { 
    # AWK version, security risk
    awk "BEGIN { print $*; exit; }" # Use AWK as a calculator
    # If you want to keep what you did previously:
    # BC version, possibly less of a security risk, but an extra process is involved
    # echo "$*" | bc -l | awk '{printf "%f\n", $0}'
    echo "$0: $1: command not found" 1>&2 # Send error to STDERR
    exit 127 # Keep same exit status as otherwise
}
```

From the bash man page: (This functions gets invoked when bash runs out of other options)

```
If  the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no
slashes, bash searches each element of the PATH for  a  directory  con-
taining  an  executable  file  by that name.  Bash uses a hash table to
remember the full pathnames of executable files (see hash  under  SHELL
BUILTIN  COMMANDS  below).  A full search of the directories in PATH is
performed only if the command is not found in the hash table.   If  the
search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for a defined shell function
named command_not_found_handle.  If that function exists, it is invoked
with  the  original command and the original command's arguments as its
arguments, and the function's exit status becomes the  exit  status  of
the  shell.  If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error
message and returns an exit status of 127.
```

Comment: This is a horrible security risk.... The error handler executes arbitrary `awk` code.... (One of the reasons why this is a bad idea...) (`bc` might be more limited than `awk` in what it will run...)

Comment: The security risk might be overestimated... If you have access to a shell on a box, you can anyway run arbitary commands... It might mainly make pasting stuff into the shell accidentally dangerous in a different way...

Comment: +1 for the deliciously devious idea of using the command-not-found handler as a utility. For humanitarian reasons you may want to explain clearly that this is _very strongly_ not recommended in production...

Comment: @AlexP: "It is a bad idea" is there ;) There is http://xon.sh/ as well, which mixes python with a bourne-like shell... (This is where that starts to look like a bad idea: http://xon.sh/tutorial.html#python-mode-vs-subprocess-mode )

Comment: I see now why it's a terrible idea. Live and learn. Thanks!